# Using Pandas, how do I strip part of a cell from an Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks in advance, I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours now. I have a column named 'CaseNumber'.  the data in that column is structured as 'Case ID Number - 00123456'.

I am trying to create a loop that will go through the entire sheet and strip 'Case ID Number - 00'. So the final output would just be the 6 digit number set.

So far I have found the attribute *.strip('Case ID Number - 00')* but I cannot find the logic to create the for loop.

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2):

String operations on particular columns (or series) can be done by appending `.str` to the series. You can use the following command to get your output:

```
>>> df['Case Number'].str.strip('Case ID Number - 00')
```

You can refer to the documentation here [Working with text.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)